# How to run copy-item (as admin) inside a non-elevated powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell

so I have a ps1 script which I'm running inside a **non-elevated** powershell windows.

But I want to modify my script so I can run copy-item and this needs to write to one of the folders inside c:\windows.

I've looked at copy-item and there's a parameter called "credential" but I do not know the admin password for my setup.

I'm hoping something like Debian's "sudo cp -a myfilehere.txt /etc/" would be possible.

Comment: The directory you want write to is protected and requires elevated permissions.  You would have to disable UAC at the group policy level to avoid this requirement.  I don't advise doing so.  If you don't have the Administrator creditials then you are out of luck and can't do what you want

Comment: You can't run a cmdlet as an Administrator in a non-elevated PowerShell command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Copy-Item as Administrator you should start a PowerShell as Administrator like:

```
Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList "copy source-dir/file.txt dest-dir/" -Wait -Verb RunAs
```

In my use-case, I wait end of copy, but it not mandatory.
The drawback of this solution is that -NoNewWindow is not available then.